# if read var is empty return to ask question again in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting, ubuntu-18.04

Im new at bash scripting and i'm trying to make script that ask for "DB Name", and if the db name is empty he will asked again until the user will write something.
My code is:

```
echo "Enter DB name"
read dbname
db_name="$dbname"
if [ -z $db_name ]
then
        echo "DB Name can't be empty"
else
        mysql -u root -p$mroot_pass -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $db_name;"
        echo "DB Name set to $db_name"
fi
```

Any suggestions? I tried to find some answered on the net but didn't find a solution
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a while loop to loop until the user supplied a valid input.

So something like:

```
while [ -z $db_name ]; do
    echo "Enter DB name"
    read db_name
done

# Do cool thing with $db_name
```

If you want to tell the user that their input is invalid, you could move the validation into the loop.

```
while true; do
    echo "Enter DB name"
    read db_name
    if [ -z $db_name ]; then
       echo "DB name can't be empty"
       continue # Go to the top of the loop
    fi

    break # Valid input given so exit the loop.
done
# Do cool thing with $db_name
```

Note that using continue and break reduced the code indentation.

(You mixed dbname and db_name variable names btw)

Comment: Thank you a lot, actually there is something wrong with your second solution, I tried it and when im running the script im getting:  ./test.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: Add the missing *shebang*. The `while true do` should be `while true; do`

Comment: No problem ;) Andehh whoops, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
until [[ $dbname ]]; do read dbname; done
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).